# Наследования прав сервисных аккаунтов для расшаренных Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

Возникла необходимость работы с расшаренными листами GoogleSheets. Для этой цели я создал сервисный аккаунт типа my_service_acc@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com с ролью Owner

Проблема в том, что если книга доступна только для основной учётной записи google, то я получаю ошибку

> gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 403, 'message': 'The caller does not have permission', 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}

Если же добавить доступ для my_service_acc@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com, то код отрабатывает без ошибок. Существует ли возможность наследования прав на расшаренные листы для сервисных аккаунтов? Мой код

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

gc = gspread.service_account(filename=r'credentials\my_project-dsdfew56ss.json')
gs_filepath = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/asmdlaskmdkalsmlkmads?usp=sharing"

gsheet = gc.open_by_url(gs_filepath)
wsheet = gsheet.worksheet("Anketa")

cval = wsheet.acell('M5').value
wsheet.update('A2', 'some text')
```

Comment:  "с ролью Owner" проекта? Файлы не наследуют права проекта.

Comment: Проблема, видимо, в том, что доступ владелец файла открывал для основной учётной записи google, а я пытаюсь манипулировать файлом из-под технической учётной записи. С яндексовым API такой проблемы нет, а с гуглодокамии не знаю как обходить

Comment: У Яндекс вообще нет таких сущностей =) Владелец файла должен предоставить доступ для вашего сервисного аккаунта, или вы должны заполучить действующий токен владельца для манипуляций.